# Very Simple Regex for experts

Tags: java, regex

I want to `find` and `replace` placeholders in a text (using regex).

```
String s = "This is a test {replace_me}. And this is another {replace_me_too}."

s.replaceFirst(regex, newString);
```

How would the regex look like when I want to replace the first occurence of a string like `"{*}"`.

I have tried this

```
url = url.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("{") + "*" + Pattern.quote("}"), param);
```

Comment: url = url.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("{") + "*" + Pattern.quote("}"), param); but its not replacing the whole search string.

Comment: add it in your question then

Comment: do you have an answer for this?

Comment: language you are using?

Comment: i am using java but the question deals about the regex.

Comment: `replace` cannot be done by `regex`

Comment: what do you want the matched string to be replaced with?

Comment: i update the code above...i want to replace it with any other string (doesnt matter)

Comment: are there cases like `{replac{{{}e_me}`?

Comment: no just the above example like

Comment: check this :- https://regex101.com/r/eV8xH0/3

updated the link

Comment: thats it - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll()` function to replace all occurences if you want.

*Java Code*

```
String REGEX = "\\{[^}]*\\}";
String INPUT = "This is a test {replace_me}. And this is another {replace_me_too}.";
String REPLACE = "xxx";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); 
INPUT = m.replaceFirst(REPLACE);
System.out.println(INPUT);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/epcV9b)**